# spring webflow and thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf, spring-webflow

For a new Spring (Boot) application I'm considering using Spring WebFlow. As other applications we use are using Thymeleaf for views, base templates are available and I very much want to reuse those.

The problem however is that Spring WebFlow and Thymeleaf don't work together. I did a little research and concluded that I'd probably have to extend/replace at least WebFlow's FlowResourceFlowViewResolver and MvcViewFactoryCreator. As I haven't found any information on WebFlow+Thymeleaf I'm wondering if:

- Has anybody done this before and have some code for me to reuse?
- As I seem to be the only one so far who considers WebFlow+Thymeleaf, are there reasons for not doing so? (except for the current limitations of Webflow)